# What exactly is received from POP3/iMAP?

Tags: imap, pop3

I'm working on the front end development of a custom mail system and at this point I've been using simple HTML to display data based upon my own received e-mails, however now I would like to create a table in my database of the information which is received upon connecting from on POP3/iPOP server.

Using Outlook.com you can rigth-click a mail and view source however I am oblivious to as whether this is the information gathered upon connecting.

I'm hoping this is the sort of question I can ask on here, basically I'd like to have an answer showing one example of all information received from the iPOP/POP3 server with information and/or useful resources.

### To Clarify

I'm working on the front-end development and would like realistic information that would be gathered to create a dummy database table, thus meaning I can echo the information and create functions and whatnot prior actually establishing a connection to POP3 or iMAP

Comment: Search for RFCs "RFC POP3"...

Comment: You'll need to go through the lengthy specifications on IMAP and POP3; that will give you an idea of how things should look, then you can make IMAP and POP3 requests to real mail servers and see how widely it varies from server to server.

Comment: If I understant correctly, you are looking for e-mail headers

Comment: @AlejandroC. I'm going to update my question now. I'm now wanting to connect right now, just create a dummy database table of realistic information to complete my front-end development prior actually connecting.

Comment: From POP3, you generally get full MIME messages.  from IMAP, you can get full MIME messages, or you can ask the server to parse it into pieces and get the pieces you want.  The best information for this is the RFCs.

Comment: This information will be stored in my database such as the the from information, subject, message and whatnot. If I could have an answer explaining a little more such as the message, whether that would be sent and stored via a HTML value. Working on a very low funded project and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble, but writing an email client is extremely involved and cannot really be done on the cheap.   There is a lot of background information :  mime headers, encoded words, body encoding, mime structures, text encoding, and more.  Both IMAP and POP3 are capable of giving you the raw message (what you see when you view source) or just the headers (assuming your pop3 server supports TOP) which you can parse and do with as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP is a classic internet protocol in that it contains lots of plain text. You can use POP effectively using just `telnet server.doma.in 110` to see how a server responsds to a particular command, and Wireshark will dump the commands user by Outlook and the server's responses, both in a format that'll suit your tests well.